# How to share memcache items across 2 apps locally using google app eninge sdk

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have 2 Google App Engine applications which share memcache items, one app writes the items and the other apps reads them. This works in production. however - locally using the SDK, items written by one app are not available to the other. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of code, two apps, which work sharing memcache between two GAE apps in prod but fail locally?  Without seeing such code it is, of course, pretty impossible to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually two different App Engine **apps** cannot see the same items in memcache.  Their memcache spaces are totally isolated from each other.

However two different **modules** of the same app use the same memcache space and can read and write the same items. Modules act like sub-apps. Is that what you meant?

It is also possible to have different **versions** of an app (or module) running at the same time (for example to do A/B testing), and these also use the same memcache space.